# Is it feasible to maintain directory structure when backing up to AWS S3 Glacier classes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to backup 2TB from a shared drive of Windows Server to S3 Glacier

There are maybe 100 folders (some may be nested ) and perhaps 5000 files (some small like spread sheets, photos and other are larger like server images. My first question is what counts as an object here?

Let’s say I have Folder 1 which has 10 folders inside it. Each of 10 folders have 100 files.

Would number of objects be 1 folder + (10 folders * 100 files) = 1001 objects?

I am trying to understand how folder nesting is treated in S3. Do I have to manually create each folder as a prefix and then upload each file inside that using AWS CLI? I am trying to recreate the shared drive experience on the cloud where I can browse the folders and download the files I need.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 does not actually support folders. It might *look* like it does, but it actually doesn't.

For example, you could upload an object to `invoices/january.txt` and the `invoices` directory will just magically 'appear'. Then, if you deleted that object, the `invoices` folder would magically 'disappear' (because it never actually existed).

So, feel free to upload objects to any location without creating the directories first.

However, if you click the **Create folder** button in the Amazon S3 management console, it will create a **zero-length object with the name of the directory**. This will make the directory 'appear' and it would be counted as an object.

The easiest way to copy the files from your Windows computer to an Amazon S3 bucket would be:

```
aws s3 sync directoryname s3://bucket-name/ --storage-class DEEP_ARCHIVE
```

It will upload all files, including files in subdirectories. It will *not* create the folders, since they aren't necessary. However, the folder will still 'appear' in S3.

Comment: I am referring to S3 glacier though. And I am worried about the number of objects. Does each file and folder counts as a put request when uploading ? Can i see the list of files and folders once I upload it (like an index) ? Or that would count as Get or LIST request ?  If I zip them to reduce PUTs, then I can’t see what’s in the archives.

Comment: The PUT charge for Glacier Deep Archive is `$0.05 per 1000 requests` (and even cheaper for other Glacier storage classes), so it is not a significant charge. (5000 files = $0.25)

Comment: The Data IN to AWS is free right? So why do they charge for uploading? Am I misunderstanding what PUT request is? `aws s3 sync directoryname s3://bucket-name/ --storage-class DEEP_ARCHIVE` Would these be several PUT requests?

Comment: As the pricing page says, "You pay for requests made against your S3 buckets and objects." This is separate to charges for storage and for Data Transfer costs (from AWS to the Internet). A PUT request is used when sending each file to S3. If a file is large, it might use several PUT requests.

Comment: So when the pricing page says: "You pay for all bandwidth into and out of Amazon S3, except for the following:
Data transferred out to the internet for the first 100GB per month, aggregated across all AWS Services and Regions (except China and GovCloud)
Data transferred in from the internet."

So uploading to S3 bucket doesn't count  as free "Data transferred into internet" ?

I guess I don't understand what count's as "Data transferred into internet" then.

Comment: The sentence you just quoted says "except: Data transferred in from the Internet". This is stating that there is no Data Transfer charge for traffic coming from the Internet into AWS. This discussion is drifting away from your original question. If you wish to ask about Amazon S3 pricing, it would likely be better to ask questions at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Comment: I am uploading from on prem to S3 bucket. I don't see how that is not data coming into S3 from internet.

Comment: That _is_ data coming into S3 from the Internet. It therefore does not attract any Data Transfer charge. "You pay for all bandwidth into and out of Amazon S3, except for the following: ... Data transferred in from the internet."

Comment: "That is data coming into S3 from the Internet. It therefore does not attract any Data Transfer charge." So aren't PUT requests when uploading from on prem to S3 are not charged ? Earlier you said PUT requests are`$0.05 per 1000 requests`. Are PUT requests not same as data coming from internet to S3?

Comment: Amazon S3 attracts charges for: Storage (will be charged); Requests (will be charged); Data Transfer (will NOT be charged).